# Linux Server is slow on running some commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, troubleshooting

I have a Linux server and ubuntu 20.04 is installed on it. Kernel version is `5.4.0-163-generic`. 24 cores and 32GB RAM.

I have database running on this server which is working without any issue. problem is when I want to run a command for the first time, it takes too long. or starting and ssh session always takes 4-5 seconds.

Here's an example:

```
$ time mysql -u root -h 127.1
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

real    0m3.663s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.008s



$ time mysql -u root -h 127.1
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.007s
```

today I saw a weird problem. I was moving some files to this server from another server in the same network segment(using LAN/private network) using rsync and it started with ~90/MBs which is normal. Then after 1GB it dropped to 50MB/s then 30MB/s and in the end it was doing 1MB/s.

I checked both servers network/disk I/O and everything was normal. then I checked my destination server and noticed load average is increasing. I checked metrics, CPU usage was under 0.2 for all the cores and from top output there was a some I/O WA per core(i think its normal since it was copying files and wait times were not consistent, they were showing up per interval on just 2-4 cores).

I have always around 200 - 400 MB available memory and 2 - 3 GB in buffer/cache. I have innodb buffer size on 25GB and I can decrease it if that would be the problem which I don't think so.

The only change I made to the kernel was `intel_iommu=igfx_off intremap=off` because my hardware have problem on some versions of kernel.

Can anyone tell me how to investigate more on this problem? I'd appreciate any idea/help.

Comment: Where is the database server hosted? Is it running on a virtual machine on your laptop, or is it deployed on a public cloud service? I'm inquiring because I encountered a similar problem with my database servers when they were hosted on a private cloud; we experienced significant latency and occasional deadlocks.

Comment: In the mean time, review system logs (/var/log/syslog, /var/log/dmesg, etc.) for any errors or warnings that might be related to the performance issues and execute benchmark tests like sysbench or IOzone to measure the performance of different components of your system, such as CPU, memory, and disk I/O.

Comment: Hey R1w, there is no warning/errors in the logs.

Database is hosted on a baremetal server.

Comment: Hey @lowkey , and the db is only server on that baremetal ?